# Can't remove regular file "Device or resource busy"

Tags: linux, bash, centos7

I'm running a CentOS 7 system and have run into a problem.  I'm trying to remove a file /etc/passwd+ which got left behind from a previous password change, but for some reason I'm not able to.  The system is returning a "Device or resource busy" error:

```
#/etc# rm passwd+
rm: cannot remove ‘passwd+’: Device or resource busy
```

To be clear, this isn't a filesystem mount point or even a directory.  It's just a regular file.

```
#/etc# ls -l /etc/passwd+ 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3192 Aug  1 09:32 /etc/passwd+
```

I'm running as root as I try to do this.

```
#/etc# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

I checked to see what processes might be using this file but found none.

```
#/etc# fuser -v /etc/passwd+
#/etc# lsof | fgrep /etc/passwd+
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1067/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

I'm not running selinux and there are no special attributes assigned to the file.

```
#/etc# getenforce
Disabled
#/etc# lsattr /etc/passwd+
-------------e-- /etc/passwd+
```

I'm also not running inside a container or any restricted namespaces.

The file is on my root filesystem, which is a ext4 filesystem.

```
#/etc# df -h /etc/passwd+
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rootvg-root   39G   17G   20G  47% /
#/etc# mount | grep /dev/mapper/rootvg-root
/dev/mapper/rootvg-root on / type ext4     (rw,noatime,nodiratime,nobarrier,data=ordered)
```

My version of CentOS is 7.4.1708 with all the current updates applied.

```
# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
# yum -q check-update
```

Has anyone seen this behavior before?  Any idea on what could be causing it?

== Update ==

I rebooted the machine and was then able to successfully remove the file.  On the assumption there might be some kind of filesystem corruption going on I rebooted from a rescue CD and ran `e2fsck -f /dev/rootvg/root`, but no errors were found.  This isn't the first time I've run into this inability to delete or move a file (it's different files every time), so it's likely to happen again at some point in the future.  However I'm good for now.

Comment: what does `lsof +D /etc/passwd+` give?

Comment: @Mike: It gives `lsof: WARNING: not a directory: /etc/passwd+` and then usage information